# Define bash function and chain `script` with it in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am having issues defining a bash function inside a bash script and getting to use it in the same script when I try to chaining it after the `script` command.

A minimal working example is this. I have file called `my_script.sh`, containing

```
#!/bin/bash

my_function () {
  echo "My output"
}

my_function

script my_log.log -c my_function
```

Which when run returns

```
My output
Script started, output log file is 'my_log.log'.
bash: line 1: my_function: command not found
Script done.
```

I do not understand why `my_function` is recognized alone, but not when chained after `script`.

Can someone explain, and perhaps offer a solution?

Comment: Does it work if you first run `export -f my_function` and _then_ `script my_log.log -c my_function`?

Comment: @terdon, It does! Thank you! If you add this as answer, I'll gladly accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that your function only exists in your script, but then you run the `script` command which invokes a new shell (the one whose path is stored in `$SHELL` or `/bin/sh` otherwise). That new shell has no knowledge of your function unless you also define it in there.

The `bash` shell supports *exporting* a function to the environment. Then all other bash invocations (even those running as `sh`) run in that environment would import those definitions.

To export a function, you do:

```
export -f my_function
```

See `help export` in a `bash` shell:

```
$ help export 
export: export [-fn] [name[=value] ...] or export -p
    Set export attribute for shell variables.
    
    Marks each NAME for automatic export to the environment of subsequently
    executed commands.  If VALUE is supplied, assign VALUE before exporting.
    
    Options:
      -f    refer to shell functions
      -n    remove the export property from each NAME
      -p    display a list of all exported variables and functions
    
    An argument of `--' disables further option processing.
    
    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless an invalid option is given or NAME is invalid.
```

Then all you need to do is make sure `script` runs `bash` to interpret that command line passed after `-c` for which you need to pass it the right value for the `$SHELL` variable:

```
SHELL=$BASH script -c myfunction
```

Comment: @stéphane I saw your edit (thanks!) removed the terms "subshell" and "child shell". I know I was sloppy with "subshell", but was "child shell" also wrong? Won't the PPID of the `script` process be the PID of the shell script?

Comment: The fact that it runs a child process (like in a subshell) is not the problem here, subshells inherit everything including functions. It's that the shell executes a separate command (`script`, in a child process) upon which its memory is wiped, and which itself executes a shell in a grandchild process (which may not be even the same unless you set `$SHELL` to make sure it is).

Answer (score 2):

To complement [@terdon's answer](/a/703027), with Korn-like shells other than `bash` that support `typeset -f` (ksh, mksh, zsh), or with `bash` as well if only to avoid the pitfalls of the function export feature (see below), I suggest some alternatives.

For the shell started by `script` to have the same function defined, you can either include the definition of that function before the shell code you're passing to `script -c`, which you can obtain with `typeset -f`:

```
SHELL=/same/shell/as/running/the/current/script script -c "
  $(typeset -f myfunc)
  myfunc"
```

Where `script` will start a new shell and that shell will start by defining the function and then invoke it.

Or pass the body of the function in an environment variable¹, and have the shell started by `script` evaluate the contents of that variable:

```
SHELL=/same/shell/as/running/the/current/script \
  MYFUNC_DEFINITION="$(typeset -f myfunc)" script -c '
  eval "$MYFUNC_DEFINITION"
  myfunc'
```

(that one has the advantage of not exposing the body of the function in the command line arguments for everybody to see in the output of `ps`).

The advantages over `export -f` (other than not being bash-specific) are that:

- then that function is only exposed to that shell where you need it in, and not the other shells that may be started in that environment.
- `bash` will fail to import a function if that function uses `extglob` operators unless the `extglob` option was enabled *before* the function is imported. With our approaches, we get to choose when we import the function definition and can then add a `shopt -s extglob` before. But with functions exported with `export -f`, the only way we can set the `extglob` option early enough is with `bash -O extglob` which is not an option here with `script`. Even `env BASHOPTS=extglob script -c ...` (which is otherwise dangerous as it affects all `bash` invocations) doesn't work.

---

<sup>¹ actually, that's what `bash` does internally with `export -f`. It even used to do it in  a very unsafe fashion which was the root of a very nasty vulnerability that made the news headlines a few years ago.</sup>.